# Routing all traffic through index.html except 'api'

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, gruntjs, connect-modrewrite

Working on a BackBone app that has this `mod_rewrite` in place to handle routing all traffic through index.html that isn't targeting a file:

`modRewrite(['^[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]'])`

It's working beautifully, but now I need to update it so that it ignores that root-level `api` directory. My API calls look like this:

`http://localhost:9000/api/customers/`

They're all breaking because it's trying to route them through index.html. FYI, I'm using Grunt [`connect-modrewrite`](https://github.com/tinganho/connect-modrewrite) locally to manage issues with routing and localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try negative lookahead based regex:

```
modRewrite(['^(?!/?api)[^\\.]*$ /index.html [L]'])
```

Comment: Would this also ignore anything that comes _after_ `/api`?

Comment: Yes it will ignore anything that comes after /api/ also.